# MvvmCross.Forms - Custom NavigationBar (with SearchBar in it)

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

What is the best way to add a SearchBar to the NavigationBar in a Xamarin.Forms / MvvmCross.Forms App? While Xamarin.Forms added a simple way through Shell for this, this is not yet supported by MvvmCross and therefore not an option. So I think it will result in custom renderers for the navigation page on each platform. But is this really the best way to do this?

Comment: You can create a custom renderer of `MvxContentPage` . Check https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/158436/wrap-text-in-title-in-navigation-bar-instead-of-default-ellipsis

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT yea I already thought I have to go that route. I already have a custom tenderer to have the MasterDetail hamburger menu button and the back button at the same time. Thanks for your response.

Comment: You can post your solution here and it will help more developers.